# Ruby - Block scope inside method

Tags: ruby, scope, block

I created some class

```
class Book
  def perform
    yield
  end
end
```

Then I want to call the block which will call `method1` and `method2`. However both methods are defined nowhere and I dont want to define them. Instead of this I'd like to call method_missing but I get:
`undefined local variable or method 'method1' for main:Object (NameError)`

```
book = Book.new
book.perform do
  method1
  method2
end
```

What Should I do then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to do what you ask I believe you need to redefine `method_missing` like so:

```
class Book
  def perform
    yield
  end
end

def method_missing(methodname, *args)
  puts "#{methodname} called"
end

book = Book.new
book.perform do
  method1
  method2
end

#=>
#method1 called
#method2 called
```

Comment: Great answer, I've tried to overwrite the method_missing inside the class scope and It caused that I didn't work